# Android NDK JNI dot notation method signature variable

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I have following method, which have multiple arguments dot notation :

```
static public void configure( Activity activity,String client_options, String app_id, String... zone_ids )
```

So now I want to call it like follow :

```
jmethodID configMethodID =(*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, adcolonyclazz, "configure","(Landroid/app/Activity;Ljav/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[java/lang/String;)V");
```

But the all I got is :

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='configure' signature='(Landroid/app/Activity;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[java/lang/String;)V'

Same goes with :

```
jmethodID configMethodID =(*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, adcolonyclazz, "configure","(Landroid/app/Activity;Ljav/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
```

Does anyone know the signature variable for this specific method. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct signature is whatever is output by `javap -s`. Don't try to write signatures yourself when there is a tool that does it for you with 100% accuracy.

Comment: Hey thanks, the method actually from a jar file. Which i extracted it and use the javap -s . And the answer for last parameter is [Ljava/lang/String;

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, however, I struggled to figure out the right syntax for javap. Here are some commands that worked for me when run in the terminal window of Android Studio Giraffe on a Linux system. Start off in the root directory of the project.

**Note:** Do a full build of your project beforehand so your `.class` java output files are up to date. `javap` takes `.class` input, not source code input.

```bash
# Find where javap lives. I didn't have one on my path
find ~ -name javap

# Best javap candidate was found in ~/bin/android-studio/jbr/bin/javap

# Find the .class file for the class that you want to run javap on
find . -iname Foo.class

# .class file found in ./mygreatapp/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/awesomecompany/mygreatapp/packagename/Foo.class

# cd into the base directory for .class output. Stop at classes. Don't go into com/blahblah
cd ./mygreatapp/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes

# Now we can run javap. I include -p because I needed private method signatures
~/bin/android-studio/jbr/bin/javap -s -p com/awesomecompany/mygreatapp/packagename/Foo.class
```

One final note. My command history shows that I once had to pass the android jar file as the `bootclasspath` argument to javap. I think that was because I wanted to dump out a system class instead of one of my classes. That command looked like this:

```
~/bin/android-studio/jbr/bin/javap -s -bootclasspath ~/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-31/android.jar android.os.Parcel
```